# Uncaught TypeError: Object #<HTMLDivElement> has no method 'setCapture' in Chrome

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I get this error message when using Google Maps API v3 (release channel), trying to pan around the map and I have my console window open:

`Uncaught TypeError: Object #<HTMLDivElement> has no method 'setCapture'`

I know that closing the console and reloading the page solves the error, but this is very inconvenient as I'm developing a map app at the moment and I need to test it and read debug messages.

Other browsers (Safari 6 for instance) don't show this error and panning works fine, console window open or not.

I'm using Chrome 21.0.1180.89.

Comment: Can you set up a JSfiddle or test page?

Comment: Where is your code? (Sorry, my crystal ball is broken) :-)

Comment: The setCapture should only trigger when the browser claims is IE. Can you send us the value of `navigator.userAgent` from this page? Plus, the code will be helpful, I agree :)

Answer (score 7):

I had the same problem, when i had left the settings for useragent override to Internet Explorer, in the developer tools settings window.
Unchecking the override solved the issue.

Comment: +1 for spotting this! This solved my issue to. This should be selected as the correct answer @coen :)